# Transitive Dependency issue in Data Normalization

Tags: database-normalization

I wish to find the transitive dependencies present in this table.

[image]

Here,

```
SID:     Staff ID 
PS:      Pay scale  
S_name:  Staff Name 
C_P_HR:  Charge per hour 
CNIC:    ID card
```

Comment: What are the *functional* dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

First start off by listing all the functional dependencies. Logically since SID is the primary key, everything depends on the primary key. Also, CNIC forms a candidate key

```
{SID}+  -> {PS, S_NAME, C_P_HR, CNIC, DESIGNATION, SALARY}
{S_NAME}+  -> {SID, PS, CNIC, C_P_HR, DESIGNATION, SALARY}
{CNIC}+  -> {SID, PS, S_NAME, C_P_HR, DESIGNATION, SALARY}
{PS}+ -> {C_P_HR,DESIGNATION}
```

Now, a transitive dependency needs to satisfy these criteria:

1. A → B
2. It is not the case that B → A
3. B → C

Upon inspection of all the Functional Dependencies, none of them satisfy the criteria. Thus, we can conclude that there ae no transitive dependencies in the table.